# dropdownlist with datatable

Tags: asp.net, datatable

I have a dropdownlist and  I load a value from the database

```
Protected Sub Popola_ddl_menu()
    Dim ds As New dsMenu
    Dim ta As New dsMenuTableAdapters.tb_menuTableAdapter
    ta.Fill(ds.tb_menu)
    ddl_lista_gruppi.DataSource = ds.tb_menu

    ddl_lista_gruppi.DataTextField = "Etichetta"
    ddl_lista_gruppi.DataValueField = "Etichetta"
    ddl_lista_gruppi.DataBind()


End Sub
```

.... I should insert two values ​​but I always fail if concatenate another field for example

```
ddl_lista_gruppi.DataTextField = "Etichetta" & "blabla"
```

Can You help me?

Comment: where you want to insert

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it in this manner, you can add the two columns in your SQL query to create a new column and use that for the `DataTextFeild` value. For example like this :

```
SELECT lastname + ', ' + firstname AS Name FROM employees
```

You can also check out this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810291.aspx) link.